# os.chdir() breaks realpath and abspath of __file__

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems the function `os.chdir()` changes the result of subsequent calls for `abspath` and `realpath` of `__file__`.

A simple example of this is: I have a file **test.py** within Folder1, that looks like this:

```
 Folder1                                                            
▶ tree . 
.
├── \
├── Folder2
└── test.py
```

This is the content of **test.py**:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path


def test():
    pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.chdir(f'{pwd}/Folder2')

# Path of __file__
print(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))

test()

# Path of __file is changed !?
print(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

If I run **test.py**, this is the result:

```
 Folder1                                                             
▶ python test.py
Folder1/test.py
Folder1/test.py
Folder1/Folder2/test.py
Folder1/Folder2/test.py
```

As you can see, after I invoked `test()` to chdir into Folder2, it alters the realpath and abspath of **file**. Why is this happening?

I'm writing a program that involves navigating between different directories, how should I avoid `os.chdir()` breaking my code? Should I avoid using it altogether?

Thank you.

Comment: When asking "why does ``__file__`` behave weird", it helps to include the raw value of ``__file__``.